# Making a ScrollPanel containing an AbsolutePanel occupy the full Height of its parent

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to use an AbsolutePanel inside a ScrollPanel.  I'd like the ScrollPanel to  occupy as much of the page height that it can to expose as much of the AbsolutePanel as possible.

I tried this.  But the ScrollPanel and contents do not appear

```xml
        <g:center height="100%">
            <g:DecoratorPanel>
                <g:ScrollPanel width='800px'>
                    <g:AbsolutePanel width='770px' height='1000px' ui:field='absolutePanel'/>
                </g:ScrollPanel>
            </g:DecoratorPanel>
        </g:center>
```

If I put in a ScrollPanel absolute height ( height='800px'), it appears on the page, and of works - however, I'm not really sure what the height the user has on the browser, so I'd prefer not to hardcode 800px

```xml
        <g:center height="100%">
            <g:DecoratorPanel>
                <g:ScrollPanel width='800px' height='800px'>
                    <g:AbsolutePanel width='770px' height='1000px' ui:field='absolutePanel'/>
                </g:ScrollPanel>
            </g:DecoratorPanel>
        </g:center>
```

Is there anyway to have a 100% of parent height, ScrollPanel, with a absolute panel inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,You want to set the height(100%) of the `scroll panel` .

```
I'm not really sure what the height the user has on the browser.
```

The answer to the above question is

Window.[getClientHeight](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#getClientHeight%28%29)();

```
Gets the height of the browser window's client area excluding the scroll bar.
```

The above method return an int then you can call `panel.setHeight(returned+"px")`.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of putting a Toolbar to the North of my Dock Panel - so using the window client height may not exactly work going forward...however, the idea of getting a height and setting the scroll panel in code sounds like a good plan.  I can prob ask the "EAST" panel what its height is and set the scroll panel to that height.  Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Its simply not logical. Absolute - means fixed. Why would you make absolute change its height/width. If you expect the panel size to change use FlowPanel or any other content panel.

Also if  you are thinking along responsive design you should reference gwt documents for [LayoutPanels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels) to be used with RootLayoutPanel.

Read [Design thoughts](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#Design) behind the GWT layout panels concepts which differs from earlier approach of .

Also, understand the [**resize**](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#Resize) concepts

Check and Observe GWT Showcase. Change browser size and the [**application**](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) Resizes even with grid data.

You can download the source code from [GWT](https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.0.zip) and extract the samples/showcase project. Note - the code is excessively complicated because of other features GWT is trying to demonstrate.

Comment: Perhaps I have the wrong Panel - I'm developing an internal CMS - essentially I need a canvas where users can drop things in a specific x/y location...but as they drop more items, the space needs to grow downwards - 1 product might have 50 items on the page and be 2000px long, and some 2 items and only need 400px of space.

Comment: Btw, I'm not as interested in the fact that my Absolute Panel can change size - even if its fixed, my example case is not working..perhaps I should remove the fact that I might change its size later.  I basically want to show an absolute panel in a scrollpanel and make the scrollpanel fill as much of its parents space as it can - I've updated the Q to reflect this

Comment: If you do not mind you can download and reverse engineer from google's showcase demo for gwt for whatever application layout your are trying!!!

Comment: I've looked at the showcase a number of times and the code over the last 6 months. I've also used the scroll panel in many places and they all work fine. I've been trying for a few hours to get this layout right and it's not working. Maybe i missed something in the sample app, and need to check again?